# How to figure out in Redis if the slave has finished syncing with the master?

Tags: redis, publish-subscribe

I have a server with a Redis instance running on it which is a slave to some master instance. Suppose the master instance gets some new data and replicates it on the slaves. Is there some event that the slaves publish which I can listen for in my application that the replication has completed successfully and the slave is completely in sync with the master now?

Answer (score 1):

All the information you nee will be available under #replication section of the INFO command.  You can know more about this on http://redis.io/commands/INFO under the replication section.

To know about the data that is been replicating you can use monitor command on your slave to achieve this.

http://redis.io/commands/MONITOR